# The HashSet sorting algorithm, 1-9 digits

Tags: java, algorithm, hashset

I ran on this curious topic: why does the HashSet class sort in ascending order the 1 to 9 digits, though the rest of the digits are sorted not ascending. I know about the idea that HashSet is focused on speed. But if someone could explain why the sorting happens only for the digits from 1 to 9, I would be grateful.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count[] = {3, 2, 3, 7, 6};
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            set.add(count[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }


Output: [2, 3, 6, 7]
```

In case of `int count[] = {44,32,87,32,11};`
Output: [32, 87, 11, 44]

Comment: Have you tried other sets of numbers?

Comment: Coincidence, largely.

Comment: You are taking a random coincidence that is probably related to the implementation of `Integer#hashCode()`, the size of the hashtable inside the `HashSet` and the implementation of iteration over the `HashSet`, and assuming it implies something about single-digit numbers.  This is just a coincidence.

Comment: Note it should be any number in the range 0 to 15 (inclusive) that exhibits this "sorting" behaviour, given the implementation of `Integer.hashCode()` and the default bucket size of `HashSet`.

Comment: ["It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: I supposed, maybe, it was just a coincidence. Thank you and I appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The iteration order over a `HashSet` will depend on three factors:

1. the implementation of `Integer#hashCode()`
2. the size of the hashtable inside the `HashSet`
3. the implementation of iteration over the HashSet

The observed behavior is just a coincidence.

Comment: It's worth noting that #1 and #2 are documented, #3 is implementation-dependent.